# passing array of charcter to parametrize constructor in c++

Tags: c++

I have a question about parametrize constructor in C++, I tried to create class phone and will give parametrize constructor for give it name, model and price but when I try to give it array of character like name compiler refuse like image bellow

[image: Error]

Comment: Please add code as code, not pictures. It makes life easier for everyone reading and answering your question.

Comment: What error do you get? The actual message is unclear from the picture.

Comment: Any reason you are using `char` and not including `<string>` and using `std::string` instead? As it sits, you need a way to limit the number of characters copied to `9 + ` *nul-terminating* character. Otherwise *Undefined Behavior* will result if you exceed your array bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your empty constructor is missing a closing `}`.

Comment: I have voted to close as a typo, but since it is technically an answer to the question, and not a critique, I didn't fully feel it was completely appropriate as a comment.

Comment: I didn't see that you voted to close when I wrote my comment. I am still not sure whether answering rather than commenting is the correct approach in such a case, but ok.

Comment: I'll have to research on meta, or ask eventually what the right approach is.